# does max-age=0, must-revalidate revalidate with the origin server or a CDN?

Tags: http, cdn, cache-control, http-caching

many websites' html file uses `cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`, like [this one](https://surma.dev/).
According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#up-to-date_contents_always), this is the same as `Cache-Control: no-cache` for most modern browsers. And I understand how it works from a high-level.

For a page with this cache strategy, for a return visit or a refresh, the browser would send a conditional request to revalidate the cached asset, i.e. the HTML file. My question is, does this request always bypass any intermediate cache, e.g. an edge server in a CDN and go straight to the origin server (with no `s-max-age` set explicitly) or any intermediate cache can validate the cache on behalf of the origin server?

The MDN page doesn't explicitly give me the answer. My guess is that it would still go to CDN for revalidation as the origin server can proactively purge the CDN once a new build occurs to give it a fresh copy.